# how to use containsLocation in react-google-maps/api library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use the `react-google-maps/api` for maps in React. I have a polygon on my map and I want to check on each click event if the click happened inside or outside the polygon.

```
import React from "react";
import { LoadScript, GoogleMap, Polygon } from "@react-google-maps/api";

export default function App() {
  const paths = [
        { lat: 52.52549080781086, lng: 13.398118538856465 },
        { lat: 52.48578559055679, lng: 13.36653284549709 },
        { lat: 52.48871246221608, lng: 13.44618372440334 },
        { lat: 52.52549080781086, lng: 13.398118538856465 }
  ];
  const handleClick = (event) => {
        console.log(event.latLng);
  };
  return (
        <div className="App">
          <LoadScript
              id="script-loader"
              googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY"
              language="en"
              region="us"
          >
            <GoogleMap
              mapContainerClassName="App-map"
              center={{ lat: 52.52047739093263, lng: 13.36653284549709 }}
              zoom={12}
              version="weekly"
              on
              onClick={onClick}
            >
                <Polygon
                   paths={paths}
                   strokeColor={"#FF0000"}
                   strokeOpacity={0.8}
                   strokeWeight={2}
                   fillColor={"#FF0000"}
                   fillOpacity={0.35}
                   draggable={true}
                 />
            </GoogleMap>
          </LoadScript>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Based on the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation#maps_poly_containsLocation-javascript)  there is a function `google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(e.latLng, bermudaTriangle)` that I can use, so in my case in the handleClick function it would look similar to this:
`containsLocation(event.latLng, paths)`.

However, I don't know how to call this function, `@react-google-maps/api` doesn't export `geometry` or `poly`. [Here](https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#polyline) is the doc.

How do I use this function?

Comment: Have you tried loading the `geometry` library in `LoadScript`? https://react-google-maps-api-docs.netlify.app/#loadscript

Comment: I don't see a geometry prop in LoadScript (am I blind lol)? When I do `console.log(LoadScript.geometry)` I get `undefined`

Comment: LoadScript has a "libraries" prop to specifiy additional libraries to be loaded along with the base API. I'd try to load the `geometry` library since the method you are trying to use (`containsLocation`, etc.) is provided by that lib. I found no documentation about it on React but that's how you'd do it with the standard JS API.

Comment: woaaahh, yah that is it, THANK YOU! If you wanna post it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @MrUpsidown !

I added the geometry library to LoadScript, then it's in the window:

```
<LoadScript
      id="script-loader"
      googleMapsApiKey="MY_API_KEY"
      language="en"
      region="us"
      libraries={["geometry"]}
>
```

`console.log(window.PolyGeometry);`

> {containsLocation: ƒ, isLocationOnEdge: ƒ}